# Different sha calculated in client and server for the same value

Tags: java, hash, byte, sha

I have a question about this.

I created two programs, a client and a server, that communicate via socket in Java.
Now the problem is, when I receive an object from an InputStream on the server's socket, I have to take the SHA384 of the value received and check to ensure it is the same as the SHA384 computed by the client. I checked in debug mode that the received value is the same as the sent value, but when I take the SHA384 of this value I obtain a different hash than the client.

Why? The client is an android application and the server side is in simple Java.

This is the function that I call to create the hash

```
public enum SECURE_HASH_TYPE{MD2, MD5, SHA, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512}

private static String SecureHashToString(SECURE_HASH_TYPE hash){

    String hashString = "SHA-256";                              //default value

    if(hash != null){
        switch(hash){
            case MD2:
                hashString = "MD2";
                break;

            case MD5:
                hashString = "MD5";
                break;

            case SHA:
                hashString = "SHA";
                break;

            case SHA256:
                hashString = "SHA-256";
                break;

            case SHA384:
                hashString = "SHA-384";
                break;

            case SHA512:
                hashString = "SHA-512";
                break;

            default:
                hashString = "SHA-512";
                break;
        }
    }

    return hashString;
}



public static byte[] getByteHashCode(Object obj, SECURE_HASH_TYPE hashing){
    if(obj == null)
        return null;

    MessageDigest md;
    byte[] byteData = null;

    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance(SecureHashToString(hashing));

        md.update(ObjectUtil.toByteArray(obj));

        byteData = md.digest();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return byteData;
}


 public static byte[] toByteArray(Object obj){
    if(obj == null)
        return null;

    if(obj instanceof String)
        return ((String)obj).getBytes();

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    byte[] byte_array = null;

    try{
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);

        oos.writeObject(obj);
        byte_array = baos.toByteArray();

        baos.close();
        oos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return byte_array;
}
```

Comment: If the hash is different, the text was different, end of story. Check to make sure you're using the same character set, encoding, and that padding is identical...

Comment: The text is the same. I have checked it. The same text is a BigInteger for the client and server side

Comment: The *text* may be the same, but are the bytes that you're passing in the same? Meaning are you 100% positive you aren't encoding it differently? Or that one has a trailing null byte, or something like that...?

Answer (score 3):

Minor issue: for `Strings`, you rely on `getBytes()`, which uses the system's default charset.  The result can be different if the client and server use different default charsets.  You should instead use `getBytes(String)`, specifying an appropriate charset name:

```
return ((String) obj).getBytes('UTF-8');
```

But the major issue is that you use `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()` to create your byte sequence for non-strings.  There is no particular reason to expect that that method will yield byte-for-byte identical byte sequences when applied to any two distinct objects, even if those objects are equivalent in some relevant sense.  You might get that result for objects of some classes, but I can definitely write a class whose instances will not have that property.

Oh, and your method will break if you pass it an object that isn't `Serializable`.

I don't know of any way to do what you are attempting at the level of generality you are trying to do it.

Comment: My own approach to this issue is annotated Interfaces to be used for JSON serialization of the models/objects and work with those Strings instead of Java objects. If the key definition order is preserved (it typically is not by default in JSON), the toJson() Strings can be equated and so then should the hashes. This also means you can modify/version/extend any Implementing models however you choose and just maintain, rely on and test the JSON serialization outputs and hashes. Just take care that the keys that are expected are always present and that you treat null type values consistently.